# RIP Alfie Curtis, actor for Dr Evazan

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Character actor **Alfie Curtis** has passed away. His most notable role was as the irascible Dr. Evazan (AKA "*scruffy human*") from the film Star Wars: A New Hope.

Mark Hamill described Curtis thusly;

> *As horrific as he was on-camera, off-camera he was funny, kind & a real gentleman. Thanks Alf - you'll be missed.* #RIP ❤️

Comment: What was his degree in?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai - Surprisingly it was in art-history

Comment: He was also the answer to this question:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/216682/who-played-the-second-evil-motorcyclist-in-a-has-take-on-me-video

Answer (score 3):

You may not have liked Luke, but we sure liked you for giving us one of the most memorable and quotable scenes in the film! You will be missed.

Comment: I love how they gave him this massive back-story after the fact. When the film was originally released he didn't even get a name-check or a credit but they clearly recognised how memorable he was to fans.